# How do I do dependancy injection into a viewController held in UITabBarController's moreNavigationController?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, dependency-injection, uitabbarcontroller

I have an app with its main view being a `UITabBarController` subclass that holds a `NSPersistentContainer`.

Certain of the `UIView` subclasses the TabBarController presents need to have access to a `NSPersistentContainer`. These `UIView` subclasses are mostly embedded in `UINavigationController`s.

To make it easy to check which needed the `NSPersistentContainer`, I created a protocol called  `NeedsContainer` and made the appropriate `UIView` subclasses conform to that.

I grab the viewController in 
`func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController){`

check if its a `UINavigationController`, if it is I ask for its `.topViewController` and check if that conforms to `NeedsContainer`. If that is the case, I inject the `NSPersistentContainer`.

This works fine until ...

I now have more scenes than will fit on the tabBar overspilling into the `moreNavigationController`.

Here is some code, littered with print statements to help me debug whats going on

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController){

    print("\ntab selected****************************************")
    print("ViewController is type :\(type(of: viewController))")
    print("****************************************************")


    if viewController.isKind(of: UINavigationController.self) {
        print("ploughing through")
        if let navController = viewController as? UINavigationController {
            print ("**it let let navController = viewController as? UINavigationController ")
            if var actualViewController = navController.topViewController! as? NeedsContainer {
                print("actualView controller is kind of :\(type(of: actualViewController))")
                actualViewController.container = container
                print("passed in container")
            } else {
                print("Its not a NeedsContainer , its a \(type(of:navController.topViewController))")
            }
        }else {
            print("it didnt let navController = viewController as? UINavigationController ")
        }
    }

}
 `
```

Tapping on one of the options in the `moreNavigationController` launches the scene but does not inject the `NSPersistentContainer`.

heres the output when I select the more button in the tabBar
...

```
tab selected****************************************
ViewController is type :UIMoreNavigationController
****************************************************
ploughing through
**it let let navController = viewController as? UINavigationController 
Its not a NeedsContainer , its a Optional<UIViewController>
```

When I click on one of the options in the `moreNavigationcontroller`, nothing is printed to the console. Xcode crashes on a check that a persistent container  is nil in the new scene.

So I have discovered...

- The .moreViewController is actually of type
  `UIMoreNavigationController`.
- `UIMoreNavigationController` is undocumented but must be a subclass of
  `UINavigationController` because my code ploughed on through at the
  check.
- Xcode will throw errors is you try to refer to
  `UIMoreNaviagtionController` so you can't ask if something is that kind.
- Tapping on a cell in the moreNavigationContoller apparently does not
  call  `func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController,
  didSelect viewController: UIViewController)`

So, how do I inject the `NSPersistentContainer` from an option thats ended up on the `moreNavigationController` ?

As a workaround but not an answer to my question, I realised while writing this that the classes that need the `NSPersistentContainer` could access their `.tabBarController` property and reach back into it and grab the `persistentContainer`. This works , I've tried it, but it seems the wrong approach compared with injecting a dependency from my `UITabBarController` subclass.

Comment: Did you check whats in navigationcontroller viewcontrollers for the more one.

Comment: Gihan - I tried  -  print(" = \(moreNavigationController.viewControllers  )") and got  = moreNavigationController viewControllers = [<UIMoreListController: 0x176ad3b0>]  .UIMoreListController is also undocumented but even so  if i could see the controllers, I wouldn't know which ones to inject . I suppose i could just inject them all ?

Comment: Only UIMoreListController in it ? can you check in variable view or PO the object .

Comment: Xcode won't let you type UIMoreNavigationController/UIMoreListController without throw up an error that prevents compilation so you can't ask if an object's type is one of those

Comment: But you should be able to PO navigationController.viewControllers ? Any how Is it possible for me to see your code

Comment: I gave up on trying to inject the object when a particular tab is selected & instead iterated through the TabBarController's viewControllers property and injected all the views from the TabBarController's viewDidLoad method.  I'm presuming this has had some memory implications  but it works and gets around the selecting an option in the MoreNavigationController not triggering the didSelect method on the TabBarController issue and the fact that Apple seemingly dont want you messing around with the moreNavigationController. I'm still curious about how to do it , if anyone out there knows

Comment: Please try this one last time self.tabBarController.moreNavigationController.viewControllers and see if there is anuthin in it

Comment: Hello again Gihan - moreNavigationController.viewControllers is , obviously an array of ViewController - its got a count of 1 asking Xcode to print its typeOf tells me it a a UIMoreListController but as i said before Xcode won't let you cast the view controller as a UIMoreListController  -Use of undeclared type 'UIMoreListController' -  so you can't investigate whats in there - This appears to be a dead end.

Comment: if let array = self.viewControllers {
            var newSet = Set(array).symmetricDifference(self.childViewControllers)
        }  Try this if gives you the viewcontrollers inside your more navigation controller

Comment: I did create my own project and did some tests on this issue there are few things I found, try the above list if it works I will post detailed answer with my findings